# Why Salesforce thinks I'm deploying a certain sharing model, while the metadata tells another story?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata, sharing, sandbox

I have the account and contact object metadata files with the following sharing types:

#### Account

`<sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>`

#### Contact

`<sharingModel>ControlledByParent</sharingModel>`

When converting and deploying the source to a sandbox, I get the following deploy error:

> Error  deployablesource/objects/Contact.object  Contact  ReadWrite is not a valid sharing model for Contact when Account sharing model is Private

But why?

The sandbox and scratch org used to develop are on Summer '19.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same... but I wonder if your issue is related to this known issue: [Deploying Account and Contact OWD in the same deployment package may fail](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDQWQA2&title=deploying-account-and-contact-owd-in-the-same-deployment-package-may-fail)

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy the two sharing settings separately, with Account being first. I had a similar problem, and it turned out that a standard object that had no parent (Asset) was set to 'Controlled by Parent' in OWD settings.

If this does not work, manually edit the OWD settings for the target org. This incidentally will be blocking deployment of **all** changes to the said object, not just those related to sharing model.

And funny enough, nothing stops you from selecting this option...